# How do i make a simple scrollview height = 80, width = 280, with images inside thats scrolls horizontally?

Tags: uiscrollview

I need to make a simple scroll view in xcode with width of 280 and height of 80 and with images inside thats scrolls horizontally. i want to make this programmatically.

Comment: Please demonstrate what you've already tried. It's frowned upon to simply ask how to do something outright.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean the UIScrollview, which has a guide written by apple found here: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

A guide that I personally used was this one:
http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/

I'll take you through the quick basics of adding the scrollview to your view and adding images to it.

I'm guessing you're new to Objective C, so I'll give you a quick guide. Firstly, you'll want to make a UIScrollView object. This is done by declaring the following:

```
UIScrollView *aScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (0,0,320,250)];
```

You'll notice I set the frame. The first two numbers of CGRectMake give you the x and y origin of the point while the last two numbers are for how wide and tall you want your object to be.

Afterwards, you'll want to add images to it. You'll need a UIImageview.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 250)];
```

Note that I positioned the image at 0,0, giving it a height of a 250 and a width of 320. This ensures that it fills entire scrollview's initial view.

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"];
```

You'll attach an image to the imageView. But wait, there's more. So far you've created these objects but have not yet associated them with the view. So if we are in a ViewController class (you'll have to look up what that is), the ViewController contains a view. We can attach our objects to the view.

```
[aScrollView addSubview:imageView];   // Adds the image to the scrollview
[self.view addSubview:aScrollView];   // Adds the scrollview to the view.
```

If you want to add more images, you have to add them at different x origins. So our first added image was at 0,0. Our next added image should be at 320,0 (because the first image took up 320 pixels width).

```
UIImageView *secondImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 250)];
secondImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"];
[aScrollView addSubview:secondImageView];
```

There are a number of options for scrollview that you will want to explore. The ones I found useful were:

```
aScrollView.delegate = self; // For gesture callbacks
self.pagingEnabled = TRUE;   // For one-at-a-time flick scrolling
self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO; // Cleaner look for some apps.
self.alwaysBounceHorizontal = TRUE; // Look it up.
```